# Extract string from square brackets and quotes

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I was trying to extract strings of the following form:

```
[["abc"]] --> abc
```

So I wrote `echo "[[\"abc\"]]" | sed -e 's/\[\[\"//g' | sed -e 's/\"\]\]//g'`

And it works fine but looks extremely ugly. I'm pretty much sure that there should be a neater solution for such a simple case?

Can you please advice some `sed` or `awk` enhancement for that?

Comment: I don't see anything much more elegant; maybe using a single invocation and anchoring, dropping the `g` flag? `sed 's/^\[\["//;s/"\]\]$//' <<< '[["abc"]]'`

Comment: Consider taking a step back and try to figure out what this data actually is. If it's JSON, you can get `abc` with a simple `jq -r '.[0][0]'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just looking for what is between the double-quotes, try this

```
echo '[["abc"]]' | awk -F\" '{print $2}'
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

You can use a single replacement with a capture group:

```
echo '[["abc"]]' | sed 's/\[\["\([^"]*\)"\]\]/\1/g'
```

You also don't need to escape `"` in a regexp.

Answer (score 2):

For `sed`, one option to make your command a bit more succinct is to use a capture group along with a backreference:

```
echo "[[\"abc\"]]" | sed -e 's/\[\["\(.*\)"\]\]/\1/g'
> abc
```

Comment: This solution works for the example given but what if there were two such examples on the same line?

Comment: @potong – Although the question did not explicitly state the need for global replacement, I realize it introduces no harm; I updated my answer with the global `g` flag.

Comment: Try `echo '[["abc"]] [["xyz"]]' | sed -e 's/\[\["\(.*\)"\]\]/\1/g'` vs `echo '[["abc"]] [["xyz"]]' | sed -e 's/\[\["\([^"]*\)"\]\]/\1/g'`. Remember `.*` is greedy and makes the longest match. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

just remove the unwanted chars

```
$ echo "[[\"abc\"]]" | tr -d '[]"'
abc
```

Comment: That breaks if the string contains square brackets, though: `[["foo[bar]"]]`

Comment: Correct, or nested quotes as well.